# Looking up a value in a employee/manager hierarchy using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lookup

I have a situation where I would like to lookup a value that is currently attached to a manager to their respective direct reports. The data set at the manager level looks like this:

```
MGR_ID        MGR_Value
1             Complete
2             InComplete
```

Employee/ Manager hierarchy looks like this :

```
EE_ID       MGR_ID
3           1
4           1
5           1
6           2
7           2
```

Now the following dataset has the manager/employee hierarchy and there I want to create a new column where I can store the same value for the employee as per their manager's. So the output data should look something like this:

```
EE_ID       MGR_ID      MGR_Value      EE_Value
3           1           Complete       Complete
4           1           Complete       Complete
5           1           Complete       Complete
6           2           InComplete     InComplete
7           2           InComplete     InComplete
```

How should I achieve this in pandas?

Comment: Where do the `EE_ID` come from?

Comment: from my raw data. so I already have my raw data where I have a hierarchy for every employee, as to under which manager they roll up under

Comment: Okay. It is difficult to help you achieve your output data without enough understanding of the input. As it stands it is not possible to make your output from the single manager's dataset. Can you update your question to outline the complete input necessary to build your output?

Comment: updated that as well..

Answer (score 0):

Try merge first then duplicate the column:

```
import pandas as pd

df_manage = pd.DataFrame({
    'MGR_ID': {0: 1, 1: 2},
    'MGR_Value': {0: 'Complete', 1: 'InComplete'}
})
df_hierarchy = pd.DataFrame({
    'EE_ID': {0: 3, 1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 6, 4: 7},
    'MGR_ID': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2}
})

# Merge DataFrames Together
new_df = df_hierarchy.merge(df_manage, on='MGR_ID')
# Duplicate Column
new_df["EE_Value"] = new_df['MGR_Value']

# For Display
print(new_df.to_string())
```

```
   EE_ID  MGR_ID   MGR_Value    EE_Value
0      3       1    Complete    Complete
1      4       1    Complete    Complete
2      5       1    Complete    Complete
3      6       2  InComplete  InComplete
4      7       2  InComplete  InComplete
```